# Single sign-on with Chrome Custom tab

Tags: android, single-sign-on, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs

**Background**

I am implementing SSO (Single sign-on) for my android app and once user want to login
i sent him to CustomTab with redirect url and once he is authenticated he get back to the app again with code and i use this code further to give him access token to start use the app.

**Problem**

When i try to login again with different email , i sent him to the CustomTab but the session is still cached in the browser and i got success code from the previous session. i want the user to enter his email every-time he navigated to the web page

**what i need**

Is there is a way to clear previous session from custom tab or delete the cache ?
so user can login every time

In case not
is there is a way to open same tab every time i send intent view action , and don't open different tab every-time i fire intent

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Custom Tabs share cookies with regular Chrome app. So you can't acces to chrome cache or other source of it.
If you can use webview in your app try it.

Comment: The RFC8252 standard explicitly advises not to use WebView. So don't do that.

Comment: Yes that's right , but as a last resort you can use webview which i don't recommend for other position